# accepted answer not giving any reputation

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I have posted my answer in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712565/java-use-scanner-to-count-words-and-lines-from-user-input/28712641#28712641)and user has accepted my answer, when i checked my profile no reputation is added, what is the reason behind it, can you please tell me?

Comment: OT: if you have at least a little sense of quality, you'll stop suggesting edits like you do. Many of them makes the posts even worse readable. Shame on approvers.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is a community wiki. Community wiki answers do not affect your reputation as you're effectively saying "this answer belongs to the community as a whole, and not to one particular user".

Is there a reason you've posted this answer as a wiki?

Comment: how to made that as non community answer

Comment: @BalaYesuCh. You have to ask a mod to do it. And Bolt happens to be a mod.

Comment: I think a small "?" button next to the community wiki checkbox would help eliminate confusions like this. Just saying.

Comment: You would have to not have checked the "community wiki" box prior to submitting the answer. The fact that you did suggests you had a reason to do so, which is why I ask.

Comment: at that time i want to made that as a wiki answer

Comment: Except the community wiki flag, there are currently no votes. But I wouldn't be surprised. Your answer now says *"you can calculate the words, lines with the following code <your code>"*. How can one get that? Are we supposed to trust you? To a code that is utterly formatted and uses some insane variable names? To be honest, I wouldn't.

Comment: @BalaYesuCh. so why did you want to make it a wiki answer then, and why have you changed your mind?